# Does Goblin Slayer ever leave his armor?

Tags: goblin-slayer

In Season 1 and Season 2 of the Goblin Slayer anime, Goblin Slayer never leaves his armor. Not to eat, not to sleep, etc. I think he once said he has to be prepared to kill Goblins at any time. But he should leave his armor eventually right? I mean, how does he take a shower?

Is it ever shown or said in the Novel or Manga if he ever leaves his armor?

Answer (score 1):

He's certainly highly averse to removing any part of his armor. In social situations, he may lift his helmet visor partway in order to eat or drink. I don't recall if he ever does so while in combat.

In S1E8, he was gravely wounded by the Goblin Champion. He later awoke to find himself removed from his armor, freshly resurrected by Priestess and Sword Maiden. We see numerous scars from his prior experiences.

During the celebration at the end of S1, Priestess asks him to remove his helmet. This is the only request we see him honor thus far, and all in attendance marvel at the sight.

To what degree he maintains such caution, and how much self-care he might be sacrificing, is not shown further in the anime. The wiki does mention that he frequently tasks the blacksmith with repair of one set of gear while adventuring with another identical set.